# Access first element of a List column in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a column which is of type list.

[image]

I want to access the first element of the column.

Is there a way to access the list element using the index value?

I tried

```
FIRSTNONBLANK(Table[Column Name])
Table[Column Name]{0}
Table[Column Name][0]
```

But they didn't work

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Comment: its a SharePoint people picker column with multiple users enabled

Comment: what do you mean by "type list"? there is no such column type in PowerBI.

Comment: I've updated the question please check it @RADO

Comment: @VigneshSubramanian:  I might be wrong, but I think there is a confusion here between Power BI and Power Query. Power BI is a reporting engine that uses DAX language. Power Query is a data preparation (ETL) engine, that uses language called "M". Your picture shows that your are in a Power Query window, while trying to DAX. I don't think it's possible - you will have to use "M". In "M", list item can be accessed as MyList{position} (see here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/29b1fdcc-3533-4bb9-bf47-2c6d876ea5f4/power-query-get-list-value-by-position?forum=powerquery)

Comment: @RADO You are correct that this must be done in the query editor using M rather than DAX. I'd just like to point out that the query editor is part of the Power BI Desktop program so it is effectively a Power BI and a Power Query question, IMO.

Comment: What do you mean by first element of the column? You want the whole list in row 1 or for each row you want the first element of each list?

Comment: for each row, you want the first element of each list

Answer (score 1):

You can access the list first element by using **List.First()** method

*Example 1:*

**input:**  {a:1,b:2}

```
List.First({a:1,b:2})
```

**output:** {a:1}

*Example 2:*

**Input:** input list contains an array of JSON objects

[image]

using List.First(): creating a custom column

[image]

**output:** received each list first object in a new column

[image]

then expand the records

[image]